# How to show a section if a list if not empty in Moustache?

Tags: mustache

This is a question about Mustache syntax. I'm using [clostache](https://github.com/fhd/clostache) but I don't think that makes a difference.

The 'Section' operator appears to be overloaded to mean

> if the bound value is boolean, it means `if`, but if it's a list it means `loop`

What if I want to show a section if a value is non-false but not iterate? For example (creating an example operator with a `%` character)

```
{{%people}}
<p>There are people. Here they are:</p>
<ul>
{{#people}}<li>{{name}}</li>{{/people}
{{/people}}
```

This seems like a very common use case but I can't obviously see the syntax for it. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately what you've described is not possible. In your JS code you must create a new section for the title and set it to `true` if the length of `people` is greater than 0.